# "Special Kind of Infinity" Showing Up In the Product of a Bra and Ket Vector Under and Integral

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, integration, dirac-delta-distributions

As a summer "project" I have been reading through Paul Dirac's *Principles of Quantum Mechanics* to try and acquaint myself with Quantum Theory. In a section on observables, Dirac poses a situation:

Suppose $|X⟩$ and $|Y⟩$ are two kets expressable as integrals of the observable $ξ$ (where the range of integral is over the range of eigenvalues of observable $ξ$),

$$|X⟩ = \int |ξ^{'}x⟩ dξ^{''}\tag{p.39}$$ and $$|Y⟩ = \int _{\ }^{\ }|ξ^{''}y⟩dξ^{''}\tag{p.39}$$

Where the $x$ and $y$ are placed within the integral to "distinguish the two integrands".
Taking the conjugate of $|X⟩$ and multiplying by $|Y⟩$ we get,

$$⟨X|Y⟩ = \iint \langle \xi^{'}x|\xi^{''}y\rangle dξ^{'}dξ^{''}\tag{28}$$

Now, Dirac tells us to consider first the integral:

(    $$\int \langle \xi^{'}x|\xi^{''}y\rangle dξ^{''}\tag{29}$$

Clearly enough, from the orthogonality theorem which says that eigenvectors belong to different eigenvalues of an observable are orthogonal, the integrand will vanish for all $ξ$ except for when $ξ′′ = ξ′$. To quote Dirac:

> "If the integrand is finite at this point...the integral vanishes, and if this holds for all ξ', then we get that <X|Y> vanishes. Now in general <X|Y> does not vanish, so in general ⟨ξ′x|ξ′′y⟩ must be infinitely great in such a way as to make (29) non-vanishing and finite." (Dirac, Principles of Quantum Mechanics)

He goes on to say that this form of infinity will be discussed in his section on the delta function and then speaks about how the condition of assumed normalizability must be relaxed in order to solve most practical physical problems. Cool.

My question comes in response to his deduction that the integrand must be "infinitely great in such a way" to make the integral (29) non-vanishing. As a young student, never before in my life have I encountered an integrand of finite length that, when integrated over would output zero. Nor have I encountered an integral that could be "infinitely great" and still integrable.

If someone with more experience in Quantum Mechanics could come and clear this up for me, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function

Comment: The Dirac delta is simply a (fairly cheap) trick used by physicists to avoid functional analysis. The mathematicians had all of this figured out well before Dirac and far more generally, as far as I know, the correct math just happens to be "overkill" for most applications in physics.

Comment: @FlatterMann The way I understand it, the mathematicians *didn't* have this stuff worked out before Dirac.  The Dirac delta had been used (at least implicitly) before that (as far back as 1827, according to Wikipedia), but Dirac introduced the explicit delta function and the arithmetic associated with it, and the complete rigorous theory of distributions wasn't worked out until 1945 (Schwartz).

Comment: @march Exactly. This is not really an invention of Dirac, at most he may have re-invented it without knowing about previous work. It also doesn't solve any real physics problem. It's merely a handy notation tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Ghoster](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/321853/ghoster) said in their comment, Dirac is referring to his [delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function). This is a very strange idea from a mathematical point of view, but in physics it is quite common. It's even used for charge distributions in E&M (for point charges).

If you want to think of it in strict mathematics, it's probably best to squint a little bit. Now, the Dirac delta function isn't a function in our normal understanding, taking on an infinite value at $x=0$: $\delta(0)=\infty$. But we can consider it a *limit* of functions:
$$
f(x,w) = \begin{cases}
0&\text{if }x<-w\\
\frac{1}{2w}&\text{if }-w\le x\le w\\
0&\text{if }x>w
\end{cases}
$$
$$
\delta(x) = \lim_{w\to0} f(x,w)
$$
This limit does not exist since it diverges at $x=0$. Therefore we cannot treat $\delta$ as a function in strict terms. The intuition is presented by Dirac, but here's one formal way of considering it:

Whenever you are asked to evaluate an expression with the Dirac delta function, separate it out into the limit and the $f(x,w)$ components, putting the limit at the very outside. For example, in an integral:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x)\,dx \rightarrow \lim_{w\to0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,w)\,dx = 1
$$
This limit converges to 1 because it is 1 for *any* $w$. Similarly, most expressions with the Dirac delta will become mathematically formal if you bring the limit to the outside of the expression. Here's another example (a common one which gives the Dirac delta another name: the sampling function):
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\delta(x)\,dx \to \lim_{w\to 0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)f(x,w)\,dx = g(0)
$$
Here, the Dirac delta "samples" the function $g$ at $x=0$. We can take this a step further and find $g(a)$:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\delta(x-a)\,dx \to \lim_{w\to 0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)f(x-a,w)\,dx = g(a)
$$

Comment: Ah! Thank you for the help. I did not realize that Dirac was essentially setting up the intuition for developing the Delta function. Also, after all my readings about the Delta function, I somehow missed the bit about infinity. Thanks for clearing things up!

Comment: @eigenSchoob Happy to help! If no other explanations or answers are needed, could you mark my answer as accepted? It helps others know quickly whether more elaboration is necessary.

Comment: Yes, of course, my apologies. I am very new to the site and am still getting the hang of things. Thanks for the reminder :)